# "Coniferous tree" and "deciduous tree" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, plantas

What would you call "coniferous tree" and "deciduous tree" in Spanish?

Suggestions:

- coniferous tree = árbol de coníferas, conífera
- deciduous tree = árbol de hoja caduca, árbol caducifolio

Answer (score 6):

Let's see the English definitions:

- [Coniferous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coniferous): a bush or tree (such as a pine) that **produces cones** and that usually has leaves that are **green all year**.
- [Deciduous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deciduous): having **leaves that fall off** every year.

Now let's see the DRAE definitions for your options about *coniferous*:

> **[conífero, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AKGTyl9)**
>
> Del lat. *conĭfer, -ĕri*.
>
> 1. adj. *Bot.* Dicho de un árbol o de un arbusto: Del grupo de las gimnospermas de **hojas persistentes**, aciculares o en forma de escamas, fruto en cono, y ramas que presentan un **contorno cónico**; p. ej., el ciprés, el pino o la sabina.

And now the definitions for your options about *deciduous*:

> **[de hoja caduca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KYSU0CJ)**
>
> 1. loc. adj. Dicho de un vegetal: Que, con las estaciones, **pierde las hojas** y las renueva.
>
> **[caducifolio, lia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6bLIkMz)**
>
> Del lat. *cadūcus* 'caduco' y *folium* 'hoja'.
>
> 1. adj. *Bot.* Dicho de un árbol o de una planta: De **hoja caduca**, que se le cae al empezar la estación desfavorable.

So it seems that all your options are perfectly valid. In the first case I would say just *conífera*.

Comment: Is also common in coloquial speech (or at least I've heard it a lot) to just talk about "árboles caducos", which is technically incorrect but understandable (and shorter).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Carlos Alejo's earlier answer, in my experience I've heard "conífera" used interchangeably with "árbol de hoja perenne" (evergreen tree), although coniferous trees are technically a subset of evergreens, according to their definition.